# Error showing when i am connecting my AWS phpadmin by terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0444 for '/Users/test/Downloads/LightsailDefaultKey-ap-south-1.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/Users/test/Downloads/LightsailDefaultKey-ap-south-1.pem": bad permissions
bitnami@***.***.*.**: Permission denied (publickey).
% sudo ssh -i /Users/test/Downloads/LightsailDefaultKey-ap-south-1.pem   -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 bitnami@***.***.*.**
Password:
The authenticity of host '***.***.*.**' can't be established.

Answer (score -1):

Since we were using the ubuntu system inside windows to run the ssh command. It was not working. So you have to do

**`sudo ssh ...`**